# Amd and Linux chipset drivers

Tags: amd

I'm currently running Windows 10 on AMD Notebook and my CPU is A6 6310.I recently discovered that I have AMD chipset drivers installed on windows but at the Linux side when I run `sudo tlp-stat` I see my AMD chipset devices has no driver (such as SMBus, PCIBus, etc.)

Can there be problems,errors when running Linux distributions without chipset drivers? or does Linux kernel handles those devices well also?

Answer (score 3):

The Linux kernel handles those devices too, it doesn’t need separate chipset drivers. If you run `lspci -v` you should see that the devices do have associated kernel modules.